# Doctrine State management

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Is it possible to save the state of the database at given time in doctrine?

Why? well for example lets say I seed a database with Products table and Customer Table and then we have 1 Products record and 1 Customer record. Then I do some crud activity on the Products table that I now have 3 Products and changed the name of the original first Product. But now for the next test or time I want to reset to state back to where I was done seeding So then when I start doing the Customer testing I start with a Fresh database with out having to reseed the database?

Can I for example hook into the even system and see which products gets created and then fix the database after or some kind of back up and reset it towards that state?

Any advice will be appreciated

Quick note I dont have access towards PHPunit

Comment: Doctrine has no builtin snapshot capability.  Databases do so for example, `mysqldump` works well for mysql databases.  But the normal process would be to just drop the database, rebuild the schema then load your initial data fixtures.  No access to PHPUnit?  You want something you can do in production?  If you want a more general solution which may very well be overkill then research the `event sourcing pattern`.

Comment: [DAMA](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#resetting-the-database-automatically-before-each-test) can load fixtures automatically between tests or wrap everything in a transaction and roll it back at the end, but it uses the symfony testing framework (_i.e._ phpunit). I vaguely remember another bundle that could export the current database state to fixtures, but I'm not sure if it's still maintained or its name, for that matter.